# React Array of Child Components not re-rendering even with setState() and unique keys when made with Array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

[image: UI image]
So, You see that UI in above image..., I'm trying to replicate some functionality of G-Mail - Selecting multiple items or All items. When I try to **select all**(the purple chkbox)... my child components don't re-render checkboxes even though their state variable `selectedList` gets updated. I need to check all the boxes on `selectAll==true`

I feel like I'm doing something wrong with .map()... it is ensured that `id` in map is always unique and also it is the `key` attribute for child components while mapping

**My main component** `Table`:

```js
export default function Table() {
    const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState(false)
    //gave a dummy id:0 beacause React is throwing Uncontrolled to controlled component error as an empty {} is nothing but undefined
    const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState({ id: 0 })
    console.log(selectedList)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        let newSelectedList = {}
        if(selectAll){
            dataList.forEach(ele =>  newSelectedList[ele.id]=1);
        }else{
            dataList.forEach(ele =>  newSelectedList[ele.id]=0);
        }
        setSelectedList(newSelectedList)
    },[selectAll])

    return <div>
        <ActionBar />
        <div className="overflow-x-auto w-full">
            <table className="table w-full">
                {/* HEAD */}
                <thead>
                    <TableHeadingRow select selectAll={selectAll}
                        setSelectAll={setSelectAll} />
                </thead>
                {/* BODY */}
                <tbody>
                    {
                    dataList.map(data =>
                        <TableRow key={data.id} data={data}
                            selectedList={selectedList} setSelectedList={setSelectedList} />)
                    }
                </tbody>
                {/* FOOT */}
                <tfoot>
                    <TableHeadingRow />
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In above code, `selectAll` keeps track of purple checkbox and `selectedList` is an object of all unique ids of child components as keys and 0 or 1 as values

I try to render checkboxes in child components when their `id` in `selectedList` has a value `1`

`selectedList` is passed as prop to child component

**Child component** `TableRow`(the one which doesn't re-render):

```js
function TableRow({ data, selectedList, setSelectedList }) {
    const { id, name, branch, address, phone, mail } = data
    function handleChange() {
        setSelectedList(prev => {
            return { ...prev, [id]: 1 ^ prev[id] }
        })
    }
    return <tr>
        <th>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox checkbox-secondary"
                    checked={selectedList.id} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <div>
                    <div className="font-bold">{name}</div>
                    <div className="text-sm opacity-50">{branch}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{address}</td>
        <td>{phone}</td>
        <td>{mail}</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Ignore `handleChange` in child component, it's for singly selecting elements and works fine... It isn't related to this question anyways

On `console.log(selectedList)`, I do get updated values of all ids to 1 but state of child components remain unchanged. Please help me figuring this out and let me know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: `checked={selectedList.id}` should be `checked={selectedList[id]}`

Comment: Wow, it worked, I didn't know that would make a difference, Me dumb af coming from python. But I'm curious to know what made the difference? don't they act as same?

Comment: Ok, understood, that made all the difference https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/#2-square-brackets-property-accessor Thanks again for such a quick response

Comment: @CertainPerformance This caused me another warning i don't even know why, It says `next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.` whereas it is a controlled component all the time

Comment: Random guess, perhaps `checked={undefined}` makes React think it's uncontrolled. Try `checked={selectedList[id] ?? false}`, I'd be curious to see if that fixes it

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're insane, its fixed... but idk why at first place it was undefined as I defined it. Or I think before my useEffect runs, that component is rendering mb. Thnx for your time a lot